# Npm angularjs 2 dependency not found

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular, dependencies

I tried to update my package.json with the latest angularjs2 RC 0, but is not working:

```
npm ERR! version not found: angular2@2.0.0-rc.0
```

How can I include in my package the latest version of angularjs2?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[All of the dependency names have been changed to be grouped under the `@angular` scope.](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02)

The changes are:

- `angular2/core` > `@angular/core`
- `angular2/compiler` > `@angular/compiler`
- `angular2/common` > `@angular/common`
- `angular2/platform/browser` > `@angular/platform-browser` and `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`
- `angular2/platform/server` > `@angular/platform-server`
- `angular2/testing` > `@angular/core/testing`
- `angular2/upgrade` > `@angular/upgrade`
- `angular2/http` > `@angular/http`
- `angular2/router` > `@angular/router-deprecated` (Replaced with the newer `@angular/router` package, which has breaking changes).